# Fail resolve swift package hosted on azure devops in azure pipeline, SSH fingerprint failed to verify

Tags: ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ssh-keys, swift-package-manager

I know this is common question but none of the solution working for me.

I've a swift package hosted on private repo in azure devops. In pipeline, i've setup task Install SHH key [following document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops) with passphrase and locally swift package resolve, authentication success. But in pipeline it fails with message "SSH fingerprint fail to verify".

I searched a-lot and there are few links below sharing, solution i've tried so far
Adding identity to known_host, manually calling swift package resolve.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1025313/swift-package-manager-the-server-ssh-fingerprint-f.html

https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/xcode-11-resolving-packages-fails-with-ssh-fingerprint/10388

https://bonkowski.net/posts/ios-azure-pipeline/

I'm not sure, is there any way to get detail logs?

Comment: To configure verbose logs for a single run, you can start a new build by choosing Run pipeline and selecting [Enable system diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops#configure-verbose-logs), Run. In addition , you can try the solution mentioned in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125659/github-actions-xcodebuild-fails-due-to-server-fingerprint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, it was because of dev.azure.com it should be ssh.dev.azure.com, while adding host entry to known_hosts.